Getting '... scanned from multiple locations..' while starting jetty service
I am trying to start jetty servlet container with WAR file in webapps folder and I am getting errors shown below.
2024-06-17 08:47:36.903:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp16997927-9: 
  org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlXmlTLV$Handler scanned from multiple locations: 
  jar:file:///opt/jetty/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
  !/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tlv/JstlXmlTLV$Handler.class, 
  jar:file:///opt/jetty/webapps/SGW/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar
  !/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tlv/JstlXmlTLV$Handler.class

This is part of errors I found in log file.
Currently, I am using Linux Debian, Jetty 9, openJDK 8 JRE HEADLESS and I've got the WAR file from someone else(means I did not developed the web).
I've installed http, apache-jsp, websocket, console-capture, jstl, deploy modules to start jetty service and sometimes it works fine, and sometimes errors above comes up.
My question :is it necessary for me to use maven plugin to build WAR file again or is there a way to manage this problem?

There is pom.xml file in WAR file path META-INF/maven/com.nexus/SGW/ and I've tried editing the file so that i can exclude some jar file that is clashing.
I've tried deleting some jar files that is clashing in WAR file. Jetty started without problem but the web did not shown properly


Jetty 9 is now at End of Community Support, you should be using Jetty 12 at this point in time (the only supported version of Jetty currently)

This has been answered before.
It points to a situation that can (and will) lead to behavioral problems and bugs.
See past answers on these question for more details.

Maven Jetty spams warning "scanned from multiple locations"
Maven Jetty spamming "scanned from multiple location"
Jetty AnnotationParser scanned from multiple locations warning
Jetty warning - same java class on multiple locations

